# Haskell - Check whether first order logic formula is closed/sentence

Tags: haskell

I have a declaration of data types representing a first order logic formula:

```
    data Term = Var String
              | Fun String [Term]
              deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

    data Formula = Pred String [Term]
                 | Equal Term Term
                 | Not Formula
                 | And Formula Formula
                 | Or Formula Formula
                 | Implies Formula Formula
                 | Exists String Formula
                 | Forall String Formula
                 deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

Now how can I define a function, returning a Bool value, that checks whether a given formula is closed (a sentence)? In closed formula there are no free variables, and every variable which is quantified (defined with ∃ or ∀) is quantified in its subformula only once.

EDIT:
Thank you for the directions, I think I now have exactly what you described, a list of free variables of the formula. The problem would be the second part, where every variable, if it is quantified, can be quantified only once.

For example a formula

```
formula :: Formula
formula = Exists "X" (Exists "X" (Equal (Fun "c" []) (Fun "c" [])))
```

has no free variables, so my function returns `True`, but `"X"` is defined for `∃` two times, therefore it should not be valid. Formula ∃Xφ or ∀Xφ should not contain any subformulae ∃Xψ or ∀Xψ.

The part of the function obtaining free variables where existential quantifiers are defined looks like this

```
varFree (Exists x y) = filter (/= x) (varFree y)
varFree (Forall x y) = filter (/= x) (varFree y)
```

Any ideas how this could be modified?

Comment: That is also a little bit like building an interpreter, so this a few chapters of [book](http://cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/) can help. Oh and it is not haskell specific.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard exercise. Here are some hints.

First, define a function which outputs the free variables of a formula.

```
free :: Formula -> Set String
```

Instead of `Set String` you can use `[String]`, if you prefer.
To implement this, proceed by induction on the formula. You will need to

1. compute the union of two sets
2. remove a variable from a set

You will probably need to implement these operations, or rely on the standard library (check out `Data.Set` and `Data.List` on hoogle).

Afterwards, to check whether a formula is closed you can simply use `null (free formula)` and obtain the wanted boolean.

---

To implement the part "each variable must be quantified only once", it is more convenient to recursively define instead

```
freeBound :: Formula -> Maybe ([String], [String])
```

to compute, simultaneously, the free and bound variables of the formula. When we find a duplicate bound variable, we return `Nothing` instead, marking the formula as invalid.

For instance, we need

```
freeBound (Exists "X" (Equal (Fun "c" []) (Fun "c" [])))
   = Just ([], ["X"])
freeBound (Exists "X" (Exists "X" (Equal (Fun "c" []) (Fun "c" []))))
   = Nothing
```

To implement this we probably need some "membership" test (`elem`, to check that we do not quantify a second time) and some "disjointed" test (e.g. in `And p q` we need to ensure that the bound variables of `p` and `q` are disjoint).

The `Maybe` wrapper could be a bit annoying to handle, but some relief to that could be obtained exploiting the monadic or applicative helpers. E.g.

```
freeBound (And p q) = do
   (freeP, boundP) <- freeBound p
   (freeQ, boundQ) <- freeBound q
   guard (disjoint boundP boundQ)
   return (freeP `union` freeQ, boundP `union` boundQ)
```

Comment: This strategy may need some tweaks depending on exactly what "every variable which is quantified (defined with ∃ or ∀) is quantified in its subformula only once" means.

Comment: Yes, I now have edited the question to clarify the satisfactory conditions.

Comment: @chickpeas Since you have made some progress thanks to this answer, I encourage you to spend some time thinking about how to modify your code yourself to compute whatever additional information is needed to check the extra conditions. It's not too hard. If you spend a lot of time thinking and trying things, and still get stuck, then opening a new question here on SO with some details of why you think it's not possible would be well-received. Make sure to link to this one and explain what progress you have made that differentiates the new question.

Comment: @chickpeas I added some more hints for handling the bound variables.